# Trying to do some basic socket programming on windows in C++ and having issues with library files

Tags: c++, sockets, codeblocks, linker-errors

So I am trying to implement a basic server in  C++, I am using code blocks with minGW, when I go to run build the server I get a series of errors

> ```
> undefined reference to `__imp_socket'
> undefined reference to `__imp_WSAStartup'
> undefined reference to `__imp_bind'
> undefined reference to `__imp_listen'
> undefined reference to `__imp_accept'
> ```

etc.
basically all the networking functions used in the code below
I believe the issue is with linking which was what the #pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib") was supposed to solve. I have also tried compiling with g++ main.cpp -lws2_32 and g++ main.cpp -o main -lws2_32 to no avail. 99% sure the issue is not with the code but I included it below anyway. Hoping someone has another suggestion

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <winsock2.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //initialize winsock
    WSADATA wsData;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsOK = WSAStartup(ver, &wsData);
    if(wsOK != 0){
        cerr << "Can't initialize winsock" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // create a socket & bind to an ip and port
    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(listening == INVALID_SOCKET){
        cerr << "Can't create a socket" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(54000);
    hint.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));

    // Tell winsock to listen
    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);

    // wait for connection
    sockaddr_in client;
    int clientsize = sizeof(client);

    SOCKET clientsocket = accept(listening,  (sockaddr*)&client, &clientsize);

    //if (clientsocket == INVALID_SOCKET)

    char host[NI_MAXHOST]; //client remote name
    char service[NI_MAXHOST]; //service port client connects on
    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXHOST);

    if(getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0 ) == 0){
        cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
    }
    /*
    else{
        inet_ntoa(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " << ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
    }
    */

    // closet listener
    //closesocket(listening);

    // while loop: accept and echo message back to client
    char buf[4096];
    while(true){
        ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
        //wait for data
        int bytesRecieved = recv(clientsocket,  buf, 4096, 0);
        if (bytesRecieved == SOCKET_ERROR){
            cerr << "Error in recv" << endl;
            return -1;
        }

        if (bytesRecieved == 0){
            cout << "client disconnected" << endl;
            break;
        }
        //echo message back to client
        send(clientsocket, buf, bytesRecieved+1, 0);
    }

    // close socket
    closesocket(clientsocket);
    // shutdown winsock
    WSACleanup();
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) for the functions you use. In the "Requirements" section at the bottom, see `Library: Ws2_32.lib`. Link with that library.

Comment: Does mingw support `#pragma comment (lib...`?

Comment: *"99% sure the issue is not with the code but I included it below anyway."* -- one way to offer evidence of this is to trim down the code to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the error messages. Use comments to indicate that stuff has been removed, if you like.

Comment: Thank you, I knew i had to link the  library but was struggling to understand how, I thought I had to link it to a file on my computer but was just able to type ws2_32 into the link box and it started working